# About Detroit in Nice Guys

Tags: plot-explanation, the-nice-guys

What does Judith want in the movie *Nice Guys*? Why does she say "what is good for Detroit is good for America"? She doesn't care that her daughter is dead either. What was she after?

Comment: You might want to try and provide some context for this question. Not everyone will be familiar with the movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that she wanted to help the auto industry suppress new tech (the catalytic converter in this case) that would cost them money, but be good for the environment. The porn film everyone was chasing was a thinly veiled expose about it. I don't think her relationship with the auto industry is explicitly explained, but presumably the auto industry gives her bribes and she covers up their criminal activity. It is possible that she is covering up their crimes purely out of altruistic notions about helping America but helping out a large domestic industry, but I doubt it. She must have been engaging in some illegal activity though, since she is arrested at the end of the film. The "good for Detroit is good for America" line must refer to the prominence of the Detroit auto industry to the US GDP, so anything that hurts the auto industry would hurt the US economy.

As for her feelings for her daughter, I think they were totally estranged at that point but their past relationship, while strongly hinting at being tumultuous, isn't really detailed either.

A pretty detailed plot summary is [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3799694/synopsis?ref_=ttpl_pl_syn)

Quite frankly Kim Basinger's horrible plastic surgery was so distracting I don't remember much of what she said :P

Comment: Can you add any references or sources?

Comment: @John I cited a pretty detailed plot summary. I'm not aware of any official Q&A with Shane Black that breaks down the plot. I think the mechanics of the plot, elaborate as they are, weren't really the focus of the film.